# angularjs $http.post results in 501 Unsupported method ('POST')

Tags: angularjs

Thank you in advance!

Here is my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($http) {
    var app = this;
    $http.get("./users/users.json")
      .success(function(data) {
        app.people = data;
      })

app.addPerson = function(person){
        $http.post("./users/user.json",person).
        success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
            app.people = data;
          }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                app.status = status;
            });
    }

})
```

and the index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">

              <input type="text" ng-model="app.person.firstName" />
              <input type="text" ng-model="app.person.lastName" />
              <input type="button" ng-click="app.addPerson(app.person)" />

              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="person in app.people">
                    {{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}
                </li>
              </ul>
```

And the json file, with which `$http.get("./users/users.json")` works fine.

```
[
    {"firstName":"One","lastName":"Two"},
    {"firstName":"Three","lastName":"Four"}
]
```

when I try to post I get error:

```
POST http://localhost:9006/users/user.json 501 (Unsupported method ('POST'))
```

In the Network tab it shows Request Payload:

```
{firstName:Five,lastName:Six}
firstName: "Five"
lastName: "Six
```

I am using python SimpleHTTPServer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't post directly to a static JSON file. If you want to update the file, you'll need to create a web service endpoint on the server to accept the POST request and update the file.

Comment: Sorry, stuck in same problem but could not understand this. Specially this "you'll need to create a web service endpoint on the server".  Could you please explain a bit or with code if required. Facing this problem from last 3 days. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with Anthony Chu. After coming across his answer I did some research and came across this NPM package for a [local REST api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server)  - I followed [this tutorial](http://www.betterpixels.co.uk/projects/2015/05/09/mock-up-your-rest-api-with-json-server/)  - happy days! Hope this helps.

Comment: Answered 2 years since the question's creation? OMG

Comment: Yes. I found your post helpful to the question anyways.