# How can I create a web service endpoint for a locally served JSON file

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm working through the React.js tutorial found here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

When adding comments to the page using AJAX and the post method, I get `501 (Unsupported method ('POST'))`.

I know you can't send a JSON post command locally (similar to this question: [angularjs $http.post results in 501 Unsupported method ('POST')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771628/angularjs-http-post-results-in-501-unsupported-method-post)) and I'm using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

How do I set up a web service endpoint for the JSON file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [reactjs/react-tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial) on github, there's an example server using node.js:

```
git clone git@github.com:reactjs/react-tutorial.git && cd react-tutorial
npm install
node server.js
```

Here's the server.js file.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var comments = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('_comments.json'));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/comments.json', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(comments));
});

app.post('/comments.json', function(req, res) {
  comments.push(req.body);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(comments));
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log('Server started: http://localhost:3000/');

/**
 * This file provided by Facebook is for non-commercial testing and evaluation purposes only.
 * Facebook reserves all rights not expressly granted.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * FACEBOOK BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN
 * ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
 * WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  It's also good to note that this repo uses React 0.8 so the tutorial has changed a bit, but using a node with an express server did the trick.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial is the new home of the tutorial-in-a-repo.

Comment: I see you're good to go, but in case others come and see this before we get it updated, I added servers in a couple other languages (python, ruby) if node.js isn't your thing :) See the PR (and feel free to add suggestions in other languages!) - https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/pull/5